# SQL Server query syntax in java

Tags: java, sql-server

I run this code in SQL Server and my rows was affected, but when I run this query in my netbeans javacode, it tells me data not inserted ..... any idea what I need to change? ty

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{                                         
    String query= "INSERT INTO Sales (Pro_Id, Pro_Name, Pro_Price, Sales_Quantity) SELECT Pro_Id, Pro_Name, Pro_Price, Sales_Quantity FROM Receipt";
    executeSQLQuery(query, "Inserted");
}

public void  executeSQLQuery (String query,String message) {
    Connection con = getConnection();
    Statement st;

    try {
        st = con.createStatement();

        if((st.executeUpdate(query)) == 1)
        {
            //refresh jtable data
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_ProSales.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            show_Basket_in_Jtable();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" successfully");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data not "+message+ " error");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `executeSQLQuery` defined? Can you add that function too?

Comment: that i want is just to copy data from table receipt  and paste them in table  sales any idea ?

Comment: you need to add `con.commit();` inside if statement. Can you check that.

Comment: i add con.commit(); inside if but nothing ..

Comment: Did you check what value is returned by `st.executeUpdate(query)`?  Maybe you are actually inserting more than one row. Your statement does attempt to insert as many rows as there are in the `Receipt` table after all.

Comment: I have many values on receipt table . When i run the query   so i can add the data to table sales i get the message not data inserted error .....